# C char array has different length than expected

Tags: c, arrays

I have a very simple code:

```
secret[]="abcdefgh";//this is declared in different function and is random word
int len=strlen(secret);//ofc it is 8 in this case
char word[len];
for(int a=0;a<len;a++){//expecting this will put '_' at positions 0-7
    word[a]='_';
}
printf("%d %s",(int)strlen(word),word);
```

However, `strlen(word)` returns 11 and `word` contains `"________�  @"`, thus there is some obvious memory leak I can't see. Any idea?

Comment: Read the manual for `printf` and what `%s` means.

Comment: Also it should be noted that C-"string"s need to be `0`-terminated `char`-arrays.

Comment: `word` should be null terminated

Comment: You forget that a string is not only the characters you see in it, it also contain a special character `'\0'` that marks the end of the string. All string functions expect this special character to be at the end otherwise they will go beyond the end of the string and you will have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: `char word[len+1];`... `word[len] = 0;` or `word[a] = 0;` after for-loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This character array initialized by a string literal

```
secret[]="abcdefgh";
```

has 9 elements because it also includes the terminating zero of the string literal. So the definition above is equivalent to

```
secret[9]="abcdefgh";
```

Function `strlen` returns the number of elements of a character array that are before the terminating zero. So in this declaration

```
int len=strlen(secret);
```

variable `len` is initialized by `8`
As result declaration

```
char word[len];
```

is equivalent to

```
char word[8];
```

In this loop

```
for(int a=0;a<len;a++){//expecting this will put '_' at positions 0-7
    word[a]='_';
}
```

all elements of the aray are set to `'_'`. The arry does not have the terminating zero. So applaying function `strlen` to the array has undefined behaviour.

You could change the loop the following way

```
int a = 0;
for(;a<len - 1;a++){//expecting this will put '_' at positions 0-7
    word[a]='_';
}
word[a] = '\0';
```

In this case function `strlen` would return number `7` and the program would be well-formed.

Answer (score 2):

At first glance it seems you have forgot to put null at the end of your char array (pointer).

From my experience this leads to buffer overruns or stack corruption .

Comment: Why should this lead to memory leaks? there is no dynamic memory allocation

Comment: Correct, but in C/C++ if you won't put null at the end of your char array you will get garbage in random size. For example if your char array is 5 and you didn't put null at the end of it you could get garbage in the size of 100. This is why it calls null terminating. http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/ntcs/

Comment: Dynamic allocation or not, failure to zero-terminate will not ever result in a memory leak. Other error modes like buffer overruns, or stack corruption are typical consequences.

Comment: @IInspectable, 
Edited the post. You are correct I meant exactly that.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to nul terminate the string, increase `len` by 1 and nul terminate your string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char secret[]="abcdefgh";
    int len=strlen(secret);
    char word[len+1];
    for(int a=0;a<len;a++)
    {
        word[a]='_';
    }
    word[a]=0; //or word[a]='\0'
    printf("%d %s",(int)strlen(word),word);
    return 0;
}
```

Regarding memory leak yes it can.

Answer (score 1):

One addition and one modification

1. char word[len]; needs to be changed with char word[len+1];
2. Add a line world[len] = '\0'; before the last printf line.

That will be it

Answer (score 0):

No space for the `'\0'`.

```
// "abcdefgh"
//  01234567
```

You need to define word with space for the NUL terminator.

```
char word[len + 1];
// "abcdefgh"
//  012345678 -- word[8] gets '\0'
```